# Close OleCreatePropertyFrame externally

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow

I am using OleCreatePropertyFrame to display property pages of the webcam. But, I wasn't able to make the dialog modal or close the frame externally when closing the camera.

```
OleCreatePropertyFrame(
        NULL,                   // Parent window
        0, 0,                   // Reserved
        lpcostr,     // Caption for the dialog box
        1,                      // Number of objects (just the filter)
        &pFilterUnk,            // Array of object pointers.
        caGUID.cElems,          // Number of property pages
        caGUID.pElems,          // Array of property page CLSIDs
        0,                      // Locale identifier
        0, NULL                 // Reserved
    );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OleCreatePropertyFrame` is standard API for modal dialog box meaning that it is supposed that the mesasge box is displayed until closed interactively. That is, you are not supposed to be able to close it from code.

> [This function **always creates a modal dialog box** and does not return until the dialog box is closed.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/olectl/nf-olectl-olecreatepropertyframe#remarks)

One of the ways to make the dialog modal is to re-implement property page host (`IPropertyPage` and friends) and put it into your customized UI as a modeless window or otherwise. It is quite doable overall, and mostly expects basic knowledge of COM.

Another [traditional?] trick to close standard modal UI externally is to `PostQuitMessage` into the inner message loop of `OleCreatePropertyFrame` API so that it closes the dialog box in response to non-interactive signal, and then remove pending `WM_QUIT` message from the outer message loop, added by the API after closing the dialog in attempt to forward quit command further.

Comment: OleCreatePropertyFrame doesn't provide a modal dialog box and I am able to use other background apps and the property page minimizes.

Comment: No, it is creating a modal dialog box and it is the only option it offers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have passed WId of the application as the parent to the OleCreatePropertyFrame. This helped me in forcing the dialog to be modal and not allowing to use the application until the properties is closed.